# Puppet master with different hostname/fqdn

Tags: ssl-certificate, puppet, puppetmaster, fqdn

I'm trying to use a puppetmaster for servers being both on an LAN and outside of a LAN. Here's the setup :
I have 3 servers behind a router and a VM on Google Cloud. The puppet agents connect to the master using the "puppet" hostname while the GCP VM has to use the FQDN, and that's where my problems are.

Whenever I try a puppet run on the Google VM I get the following error:

Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: Server hostname 'FQDN_OF_MY_LAN' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppet, DNS:puppet

All certificates are signed, even the VM's (which means the initial SSL cert exchange did work properly).

How can I get the VM to pull its catalog while it's expecting another hostname/fqdn from the CA than the one the puppetmaster uses ?

Comment: Update:
In puppet.conf on the master, I did add the following lines:

[master]
dns_alt_names = ALTERNATE_FQDN_TO_MY_LAN

restarted the master, removed the VM's certs on the master and the VM, re-signed..

Now the error message is somewhat different:

Error: Could not request certificate: Server hostname '$ALTERNATE_FQDN' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppet, DNS:puppet

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: I've put the dns_alt_names in the [master] section as mentioned, and then I removed the puppetmaster's certificate, restarted puppetserver and signed a new certificate. This was enough to fix my issue.